# How to check grpc server readiness from inside the application in Java

Tags: java, grpc, consul

I am having difficulty with one of my application exposing GRPC service. The issue we started with was that while doing rolling update, we were getting failures from our service due to service unavailability, which was not expected as we have multiple nodes and are deploying the nodes one by one.

We are using consul for service discovery and our application logic is to start the grpc service (make method call on Server class to start), give one second delay and then register to consul. The conclusion we came up with for the issue is that even when we call the server start method, it takes some time before it is actually ready to start serving the RPC calls. This delay is supposedly more than our 1s delay, hence we register the service on consul before actually the server is ready, hence errors.

What I am looking for is a way to check server's readiness before registering it to consul. Which will allow us to get the RPC calls on server only when the server is actually ready. **So, does anyone know any way which can be useful in this case ?**

Comment: What errors do you receive?

Comment: consul has health checking, can you use health checking?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it turned out the server was ready to take the requests. The failing request were actually due to timeout (set on the load balancer envoy). The DB pool (Hikari) was initially taking more time for serving requests hence the failure.